# All the data do not fit in the data grid view

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET page which will display entries from my database. There are about 16 columns in my query. But if I put the query with all 16 columns in my code the GridView do not show up.

It appears on the page only if the number of columns in my query do not exceed 8 columns. I don't know what to do can Anyone help me with it?

these are code samples of the query and the bask end to populate the query

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Width="900px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

And this is how i populate it:

```
Try
        myconn.Open()
        Dim sqlstring As String = "SELECT a.account_id AS 'No', a.accountid_number AS 'ID', CONCAT(account_name,' ',account_midname,' ',account_surname ) AS 'Student Name', a.account_type As 'Type', l.live_mail AS 'Acount Name' AS 'Password' FROM account a, liveaccount l WHERE a.account_id = l.l_account_id"
        Dim smd As MySqlCommand
        smd = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, myconn)
        smd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(smd)
        Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)

        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataBind()

        myconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        myconn.Close()
    End Try
```

this is query which works. If I add even one column more it doesn't show up:

```
SELECT a.account_id AS 'No', a.accountid_number AS 'ID', CONCAT(account_name,' ',account_midname,' ',account_surname ) AS 'Student Name', a.account_type As 'Type', l.live_mail AS 'Acount Name' FROM account a, liveaccount l WHERE a.account_id = l.l_account_id"
```

and this one which suppose to work but if I insert it the gridView does not show up:

```
SELECT a.account_id AS 'No', a.accountid_number AS 'ID', a.account_type AS 'Type', a.account_name || ' ' || a.account_midname || ' ' || a.account_surname  AS 'Student Name', a.account_birthdate AS 'BirthDate', l.gender AS 'Gender', l.position AS 'Position', l.office_department AS 'Office/Department', l.date_created AS 'Date Created', time_created AS 'Time Created', l.office_tel AS 'Tel No', office_localno AS 'Office Tel', l.contact_no 'Cell Phone', l.alternate_email AS 'Other Email', l.classification AS 'Classification', l.registered AS 'Status' FROM account a, liveaccount l WHERE a.account_id = l.l_account_id AND l.registered = 'NOTREGISTERED' AND a.account_deleted = 0 ORDER BY a.account_id Desc;
```

Comment: The gridview doesn't have a limit of columns, it is probably a css issue, focus on that.

Comment: Verify the concatenation on the `Student Name` column for the second select, it is different from the first, maybe you just have to use the `CONCAT` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified your DataSet has any data after the query is run? You might try pasting your SQL into management studio or Query Analyzer and see if you have a problem with the SQL code.

Also, you're using a try/catch, but not catching any particular exception. I'd change it to this. This is C#, you should be able to translate to VB easily enough.

```
catch (Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());}
```

That will show what's really happening when you load your data, and any errors on data binding.

Comment: I've tried it. No any change in the output. I believe it has something to do with the size. if I increase3 the size it appears. But I can't increase3 the size outside of the boundaries of my template. It will ruin the page. I wounder if there any way to incorporate all the columns withing the gridView

Comment: I've tried to catch the mistae this way: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", exmess, True) And it worked. The date attribute was a problem I inputed it dd-mm-yyy instead of yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Now it's working allright. Though if a user inputs a wrong data viewer page will be down again. Do you know how can I use dateTimePicker in ASP.net instead of a simple textBox?

Comment: Ajax Control Extenders from MS has a nice, and super easy to implement calendar picker/pop-up.  Google it Ajax Control Extender Calendar and you'll find plenty of samples.

Comment: Another alternative to a calendar picker is client-side validation:   <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="DateTextBox" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid date"
           Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ValidationGroup="GroupName" />